# How can I get push notifications on the android app I am building

Tags: android, notifications, push

I am building a app like Wisdom By Sri Sri. I don't know how can I get push notification on the device as I update the site with posts. Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you used a search engine to search for `android "push notification"`, what did you learn?

Comment: i learnt that we can sent through google's api but I don't know how to use it

Comment: When you read [the documentation for Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and tried following the instructions, what problems did you encounter?

Comment: Google Cloud Messaging is good option. While you refer tutorials from web, some tutorials are out of date as GCM API is updated.